# clear token when browser is closed in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

In Angular 2 application we store the token in local storage, now i want to clear the token on **browser closing** when user not check the **remember me** option during login. i did it through unload browser event but problem with that event is not fire when user close the browser from **task manager** in window.

Comment: i already implement **'window:beforeunload'** but this event is not fire when we close the browser from task manager ,

Answer (score 6):

The following should accomplish this...

```
import { Component, HostListener } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl:"./app/app.component.html"
})

export class AppComponent {
    @HostListener("window:onbeforeunload",["$event"])
    clearLocalStorage(event){
        localStorage.clear();
    }
}
```

**Note :**  `onBeforeUnload` is executing on browser close event

Comment: You should paste the code directly rather than an image.

Comment: but it is working when refreshing the page. i do not need. when refreshing thepage. can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [window.beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unload) event to clear the local storage.

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
beforeunloadHandler(event) {
  localStorage.removeItem(key);
}
```

Alternatively you can store your information [in session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) which is practically the same as local storage except the data gets cleared when the tab is closed.

Comment: it is working when refreshing the page. i do not need. when refreshing the page. can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

The below code only remove token on close and not when the page refreshed

```
 @HostListener('window:unload', ['$event'])
  async unloadHandler(event) {
    if (event.currentTarget.performance.navigation.type !== PerformanceNavigation.TYPE_RELOAD) {
      localStorage.clear();
    }
  }
```